# encrypt username in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, encryption, credentials

Need to encrypt username and password in PowerShell I've encrypted password using the below code.

```
$credential = Get-Credential

$credential.Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString |
    Set-Content E:\powershell\encrypted_password1.txt
```

But when I tried to encrypt username with the same code

```
$credential.username | ConvertFrom-SecureString |
    Set-Content E:\powershell\encrypted_user1.txt
```

Encountered with below error:

> ConvertFrom-SecureString : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters
>   for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the
>   input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline
>   input.

Is there any way to encrypt username?

Comment: `$username | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force | ConvertFrom-SecureString`

Comment: Do note this form of encryption can only be decrypted on the same PC and user account it was encrypted on

Comment: This code works but when I tried to log in to my site  using these credentials by reading these encrypted values it generates error for user name   $user = Get-Content E:\powershell\encrypted_user1.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString
$pass = Get-Content E:\powershell\encrypted_password1.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString   Error occurs as unable to convert.

Comment: Here's a question: why do you need to encrypt the username?  Just use `$Credential | Export-CliXml -Path $Path` and `$Credential = Import-CliXml -Path $Path` to round-trip.  Those cmdlets export the object with state data so they can easily be imported again.

Comment: @saikumar _Why_ do you want to encrypt the username?

Comment: I'm working on FTP file download and as per client requirement need to do so. Further, this code will be executed from c#.

Comment: Your client's requirement is nonsense. A username is not a secret and should never be considered one.

Comment: Username isn't encrypted. There is no reason to decrypt it with ConvertFrom-SecureString function.

Comment: I think the answer given by TheIncorrigible is more reasonable and you can apply in realtime

Answer (score 2):

Exporting:

```
$credential = Get-Credential

$credential.Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Set-Content E:\powershell\encrypted_password1.txt
$credential.Username | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Set-Content E:\powershell\encrypted_user1.txt
```

Importing:

```
$Username = Get-Content E:\powershell\encrypted_user1.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString
$BSTR = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($Username)
$Username = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)
$Password = Get-Content E:\powershell\encrypted_password1.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString

$Credential = New-Object -TypeName PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username, $Password
```

Comment: Pretty much neat explanation.